# Test data from ImageNet

Tags: machine-learning, image-classification

[Here](http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2016/index#comp)'s the description about the data usage for `ILSVRC 2016` of `ImageNet`. I've interpreted it with the table as follows,

```
Data          Image        Label    Changed    Release_Time
-----------------------------------------------------------------
training      1,200,000    1,000    no         always public  
validation       50,000    1,000    some       upon registration
test            100,000        0    some       final evaluation
```

My question is specific about the `test data`. Is it chosen from the **same** set of 150,000 images since `ILSVRC 2012`, although randomly ? If so, most of the `test data` has been made public before the final evaluation phase of the challenge, how the result could remain fair enough ?

Answer (score 0):

It has the same images since ILSVRC 2012. The test set images have never been released.